# Von Neumann Equation Density Matrix

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to implement the von Neumann Equation for a given 4x4 density Matrix with a time dependent Hamiltonian Hp[t_] in Mathematica

```
Hp[t_]={{1+0.1*Sin[t],-1,0,1},{-1,0,-1,0},{0,-1,1-0.1*Sin[t],1},{1,0,1,0}};
rhoIni={
    {0.261068,0.190226,0.148085,-0.190226},
    {0.190226,0.238932,0.190226,-0.141687},
    {0.148085,0.190226,0.261068,-0.190226},
    {-0.190226,-0.141687,-0.190226,0.238932}
};

Clear[rho]
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {I*rho'[t] == Hp[t].rho[t]-rho[t].Hp[t], rho[0]==rhoIni},
    rho,
    {t,0,10}
];

Plot[sol[x],{x,0,10}]
```

it gives four eigenvalues-elements of density matrix in diagonal basis- but I need elements of density matrix in non-diagonal basis.

I was wondering if you would be able to help me.
Maybe you can help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to mma.SE! Can you clarify what you mean by “non-diagonal basis”? Without knowing more, it seems your code should work & it may be that your desired outcome is ill-defined. Can you, please, clarify what it is that you desire? I might also add that this may possibly be better suited for something like the physics.SE depending on your clarifications.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The Hamiltonian Hp[t] is not diagonal. I need the density matrix in non-diagonal form (in the basis of Hp[t]) but the NDSolveValue gives four eigenvalues of density matrix which are the elements of density matrix in diagonal form.