# Unable to plot each matrix element of a matrix differential equation. The variable of differential equation is a 4x4 matrix

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to implement the von Neumann Equation for a given 4x4 density Matrix with a Hamiltonian in Mathematica. I followed the method in this thread ([Von Neumann Equation Density Matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268978/von-neumann-equation-density-matrix)) but I still couldn't get access to each matrix element of my density matrix. When I use Dimensions[sol] it is giving me {5}. So the solution is not a matrix? I don't understand what is the data type of the solution of NDSolve and how can I plot the all the 16 matrix elements separately with respect to time? My code is attached below. Please help.

```
h1 = {
   {0, \[CapitalOmega], 0, 0},
   {\[CapitalOmega], \[CapitalDelta], g, 0},
   {0, g, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0}
  };
rhoin = {
   {1, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0}
  };
tmax = 10;
Clear[rho]
sol = NDSolveValue[{I*rho'[t] == h1 . rho[t] - rho[t] . h1, 
    rho[0] == rhoin}, rho, {t, 0, tmax}];
Dimensions[sol]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Ω = .1;
Δ = 1/2;
g = 9.8;
h1 = {{0, Ω, 0, 0}, {Ω, Δ, 
    g, 0}, {0, g, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};
rhoin = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};
tmax = 10;
sol = NDSolveValue[{I*rho'[t] == (h1 . rho[t] - rho[t] . h1), 
    rho[0] == rhoin}, rho, {t, 0, tmax}];
sol[.5] // Dimensions
ReImPlot[sol[t], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

> `{4, 4}`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But how do I plot all 16 {4,4} matrix elements seperatly? If possible I also like to store each of them in some variable and play with it. Is it possible? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Siddhu  For `i=2,j=3`, use `ReImPlot[sol[t][[2, 3]], {t, 0, tmax}]` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is quite helpful.